# Consider three events, $A$ ,$B$ and $C$. $P(A) = 0.7$ and that $P(B) = 0.63, P(C) = 0.35$

Tags: probability

1) What is the largest and smallest of $P(A \cup B)$ ?

2) What is the largest and smallest of $P(A \cup B \cup C)$ ?

The answer that I found for the largest of $P(A \cup B)$ is the smallest of the two events $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ therefore the answer given is $P(B)=0.63$. This doesn't make any sense to me, why would the largest possible value of $P (A \cup B)$ be the smaller of the two events? wouldn't the largest possible value be the addition between $P(A)$ and $P(B)$?

For the smallest possible value of $P(A \cup B)$ the answer is $0.33$ how did they arrive at this answer?

How do I think about these problems intuitively?

Thank you!

Comment: The probability $\Pr(A\cup B)$ is actually bounded above by $\min (\Pr(A)+\Pr(B),1)$.

Comment: how do you think about this intuitively though?

Comment: If you can think of [Boole's inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality) intuitively, then you are done.

Comment: Most probably, you read unions $\cup$ where they wrote intersections $\cap$. True? For example the largest possible value of $P(A\cap B)$ is indeed $0.63$ and the smallest possible value of $P(A\cap B)$ is indeed $0.33$.

Comment: @Did I think it's actually union not intersection.

Comment: Then the answers you were given are wrong. Please be aware though, that the answers you were given fit perfectly the conjecture in my comment, that these are intersections.

Comment: @Did thank you for pointing that out. I didn't realize the solution given was wrong.

Comment: @Did is this answer correct? Consider 3 events A, B, and C, where P(A) = 25%, P(B) = 76%, and P(C) = 40%. Then P(A  U B U C) is at least 76% ? can I use Boole's inequality to think of this problem?

Comment: Sorry but comments are not made for questions, questions are (made for questions). Why do some people insist on playing outside of the rules of the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

You can write $$A\cup B=A\cup (B-A)$$, so that when you apply the probability function on $A\cup B$ you have the union of two disjoint events, namely $A$ and $B-A$. That is, you have $$\Pr (A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr (B-A)\ge \Pr(A)$$ The last inequality trivially follows from $\Pr(B-A)\ge 0$.

Do a similar thing taking the disjoint events $B$ and $A-B$ this time around.This will yield a lower bound for $\Pr(A\cup B)$.

For an upper bound, you can use Boole's inequality: $$\Pr(A\cup B)\leq \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$$

When you have three events $A,B$ and $C$, treat $A\cup B \cup C$ as the union of two events $(A\cup B)$ and $C$. Then proceed as before.

Comment: Trying to make sense of the exercise with respect to the correct answers provided by the OP, before answering the current, most probably incorrect, version, would have been a plus.

Comment: @Did Yes, I should have done that.

Comment: @StubbornAtom thank you for taking the time out to explain the Boole's inequality, a lot of the videos I found on youtube doesn't explain it as intuitively as your method.

Comment: @pino231 I have hardly explained the inequality, let alone intuitively.

Comment: @StubbornAtom at least now I know how to find upper bound with Boole's inequality, compared to the wiki page this is much easier to understand